# MVC 3 getting a distinct database value into a variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am new to MVC and am using MVC 3 and entity framework 4.1.

I  have the following:

```
public ViewResult Index(string id)
{

return View(db.Documents.Where(r => r.DocNum == id).ToList());               

}
```

This gives me a list of all records that contain the Document DocNum. The Document table also has a field TITLE. I want to place that TITLE into a ViewBag to use at the top of the returned View. How do I get Document.Title into a ViewBag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
var document = db.Documents.Where(r => r.DocNum == id).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
if (document != null)
{
    return View(document.Title);
}
return View("No Document Matched");
```

**Update**

If you are returning the document to the view via:

```
return View(db.Documents.Where(r => r.DocNum == id).ToList())
```

Then in the view you can simply either (Assuming Razor):

```
@{
string docTitle = "No Document Machted";
var document = db.Documents.Where(r => r.DocNum == id).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
if (document != null)
{
    docTitle = document.Title;
}

<html><head><title>@docTitle</title>...
```

Or if you are using a Razor Layout then..

```
[View.cshtml]
@{
ViewBag.Title = "No Document Machted";
var document = db.Documents.Where(r => r.DocNum == id).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
if (document != null)
{
    ViewBag.Title = document.Title;
}

[Layout.cshtml]
<html><head><title>@ViewBag.Title</title>...
```

Comment: I would like to retain the returned View I already have. But I need to also send the document title to the View to place at the top of the View (above the List returned). That's why I assumed I mgith need to populate a ViewBag with the title.

Comment: Your answer did lead me in the right direction. The following answer below gave me what I wanted:

Comment: public ViewResult Index(string id) { var DocTitle = db.Documents.Where(r => r.DocNum == id).ToList().FirstOrDefault(); ViewBag.DocTitle = DocTitle.Title; return View(db.Documents.Where(r => r.DocNum == id).ToList()); }